# passing string in XSLT to XML template

Tags: xml, xslt, parameter-passing, param

I have a XSLT. which calls a function that returns a string. Like this:

```
<xsl:param name="mystr" select="myStrfunc()"></xsl:param>
```

it also calls a XML template  like so:

```
 <li>
<xsl:call-template name="myLinks">
<xsl:with-param name="link" select="$links/link[@Id='link1']" />
<xsl:with-param name="mystr"/>
</li>
```

the xml template snippet looks like this:

```
    <link Id="link1">
     <a href="" text="click" />
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
how can I access the parameter mystr declared in xslt here??
    </link>
```

how can I access parameter mystr in the xml file?

Comment: `<xsl:with-param name="mystr" select="$mystr"/>`?
It's not super-clear what you are asking. Can you include a [small self-contained example](http://sscce.org), the xml output you expect, and the xml output you are getting instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <li>
>   <xsl:call-template name="myLinks">
>     <xsl:with-param name="link" select="$links/link[@Id='link1']" />
>     <xsl:with-param name="mystr"/>
> </li>
> ```

This is malformed XML -- the element `xsl:call-template` isn't closed.

Most probably you wanted:

```
<li>
 <xsl:call-template name="myLinks">
   <xsl:with-param name="link" select="$links/link[@Id='link1']" />
   <xsl:with-param name="mystr"/>
 </xsl:call-template/>
</li>
```

This invokes the template named `"myLinks"` and passes to it two parameters, named: `"link"` and `"mystr"`.

However, there is no value (in a `select` attribute or in the body of the element) defined for the `"mystr"` parameter.

If you want to provide a value for the parameter -- for example the result of executing a function, this can be done as follows:

```
<li>
 <xsl:call-template name="myLinks">
   <xsl:with-param name="link" select="$links/link[@Id='link1']" />
   <xsl:with-param name="mystr" select="myStrfunc()"/>
 </xsl:call-template/>
</li>
```

Then in the body of the called template, the value of the parameter can be accessed simply by referencing it:

```
<link Id="link1">
 <a href="" text="click" />
 <xsl:value-of select="$mystr"/>
</link>
```

**Or, if you need to use `$mystr` to generate the value of the `href` attribute, then do:**

```
<link Id="link1">
 <a href="{$mystr}" text="click" />
</link>
```

Comment: I have problems doing this: <link Id="link1">
 <a href="" text="click" />
 <xsl:value-of select="$mystr"/>
</link> In the XML file it does not allow me to have this 'xsl' tag. Also how can I just use $mystr, like so <a href='$mystr' text='click'>?

Comment: If you're trying to put an XSLT instruction into your XML file, then you are very confused indeed.

Comment: @Dimitre <a href="{$mystr}" text="click"> in xml..just renders the to the page as <a href="{$mystr}" text="click">. my xml is seeing it as a literal. any idea why?

Comment: @River, Michael Kay (the comment above) already told you why: XSLT code must be in its own XML document (aka stylesheet) -- you cannot embed it into the XML document itself.